# Why am I getting NoSuchKey error when trying to populate a page with images from AWS S3 bucket using MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, get, mern

Issue in MERN stack app using AWS in get request.

trying to populate a page with date using a get request. i have a object stored in mongodb that stores the image url for an image in aws s3 bucket. the variables are good as i can post data there and the key seems to match with the location of the image in the bucket but i keep getting a 404 error with the message "NoSuchKey"

here is my front end

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const HomePage = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipes();
  }, []);

  const fetchRecipes = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/recipes");
      setRecipes(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        recipes.map((recipe) => (
          <RecipeCard
            key={recipe._id}
            name={recipe.name}
            image={recipe.image}
            description={recipe.description}
          />
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const RecipeCard = ({ name, image, description }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={image} alt={name} />
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and here is my backend

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

// Define recipe schema and model
const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String },
  ingredients: { type: [String] },
  glass: { type: String, required: true },
  ice: { type: String, required: true },
  garnish: { type: String, required: true },
  method: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Recipe = mongoose.model("Recipe", recipeSchema);

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

app.post("/api/recipes", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, ingredients, method, ice, glass, garnish } =
    req.body;
  const imageFile = req.file;
  try {
    const compressedImage = await compressImage(imageFile);
    const imageUrl = await uploadImageToS3(compressedImage);
    const recipe = new Recipe({
      name,
      description,
      image: imageUrl,
      ingredients,
      method,
      ice,
      glass,
      garnish,
    });
    await recipe.save();
    console.log(recipe);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Recipe created successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating recipe" });
  }
});

const compressImage = async (imageFile) => {
  if (!imageFile) return null;
  const maxWidthOrHeight = 500;
  const maxFileSizeInMB = 5;
  const imageMaxSizeInBytes = maxFileSizeInMB * 5024 * 5024;
  const imageBuffer = await sharp(imageFile.path).toBuffer();
  const metadata = await sharp(imageBuffer).metadata();
  const resize =
    metadata.width > metadata.height
      ? { width: maxWidthOrHeight }
      : { height: maxWidthOrHeight };
  const compressedImageBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer)
    .resize(resize)
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
    .toBuffer();
  if (compressedImageBuffer.byteLength > imageMaxSizeInBytes) {
    throw new Error("The compressed image is still too large.");
  }
  const compressedImage = {
    buffer: compressedImageBuffer,
    originalName: imageFile.originalname,
  };
  return compressedImage;
};

const uploadImageToS3 = async (image) => {
  const bucketName = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME;
  const objectKey = `recipe-images/${Date.now()}-${image.originalName}`;
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: objectKey,
    Body: image.buffer,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    ACL: "private",
  };
  const s3Result = await s3.upload(params).promise();
  return s3Result.Location;
};

const getImageUrl = async (image) => {
  console.log("Function executed"); // Add this logging statement
  console.log("Object key:", image); // Add this logging statement
  const params = { Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key: image };
  console.log("Params:", params); // Add this logging statement

  const s3Result = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
  return s3Result.Location;
};

app.get("/api/recipes", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipes = await Recipe.find().lean();
    const recipeImages = await Promise.all(
      recipes.map(async (recipe) => {
        console.log("map fired");
        const imageUrl = await getImageUrl(recipe.image);
        console.log(imageUrl);
        return { ...recipe, imageUrl };
      })
    );
    res.status(200).json(recipeImages);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching recipes" });
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```